# Laravel Download and Installation

Tags: laravel

I'm a webdeveloper and I'm starting a huge project requested by a company.

I'm trying to figure out if is best to use a PHP framework or not, and in case, which one.

I know Codeigniter, but I wanted to look around to see what's the best framework at the moment. I found out Laravel is trending at the top so I wanted to try it out.

Being used to Codeigniter I usually download the zip file with all the phps inside and start working. I'm trying to do the same with Laravel but I saw you are to download and use composer to install it.

I'm not really used to the Terminal and I wanted to ask if that's the only way of installing it or if there is a downloadable version as in Codeigniter, CakePHP, etc...

Comment: use terminal - Laravel has `artisan` - terminal tool which is necessary to code with Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always download the **ZIP**ped code directly from project's **GitHub** site. You can find the base application here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel - you'll find a link at the bottom of the right column. This code is what composer downloads when you use that to setup the application.

If you want to use Laravel **you will have to use Composer** as this is what the application uses to manage its dependencies. It's not hard, as you'll only need to run a few commands.

You can learn more about how to install and use composer in the docs: https://getcomposer.org/download/